# Custom collision

Tags: mobile, lua, coronasdk

I was recently assigned to create a siple game using the Corona SDK. The main pillar of the game would be a simple event: the user should put a ball in a basket, and I should be able to handle this event.

Here is a picture for better understanding:

[image]

I successfully managed to create the collision shape for the basket, but i have trouble with the collision of the inside of this basket. My first thought was the following:

- create a new shape
- size and position it to fit the "belly" of this basket
- add it to the physics-world, and listen to the collision.

With hybrid drawing it looks like this:

[image]

But there is a problem: if i add this shape to the physics, it wouldn't let the ball fall into the, basket, it will handle this shape as a solid object as well.

**So my question is**: How could I get this custom object to collide, without blocking the 
ball to fall through it? I have read a lots of forum post with similar questions but none of them got a proper answer. There must be a way to do this in an elegant way.

And one note: **Please don't suggest checking the collision manually, with rectangle intersection**, because in this simple case it would work, but later I may need to change the shape of the basket, and then it will be useless!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Box2D has a thing called "sensor".

You just set the internal collision one to be a sensor, and it will do exactly what you want :)

Just do:

```
MyInternalCollisionObject.isSensor = true
```

Comment: Thank you, honestly i didn't thought, that it will be this easy :)